# Virtualbox suddenly not working on windows 10 host

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, kali-linux

I used Virtualbox on my windows 10 machine for about a half year and when I just tried to start any of my virtual machines eg Linux Mint or Kali all of them start fine but after the boot process I get something like a shell window with no content and no option to write content in. I can't get a TTY and all F-Keys don't do anything.

[It looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PELRL.png)

The weird thing is that this error occurs when I try to start any of my machines and before it occurs everything looks fine. Reinstalling all machines and virtualbox doesn't help and I have no idea what to do. I am using Virtualbox 6.1.18 r 142142 (Qt5.6.2) on Windows 10 Pro 20H2
I really have no idea how to fix it. Anyone can help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. Have you tried to install die Virtualbox Extensions from the Oracle Site on your Host System? If this didn’t help, try to active Virtualization in your Hosts BIOS if you didn’t already.

Thats my only ideas, Good Luck!

Comment: I tried to reinstall the extensions but it didn't help me. Now I try to enable Hyper-V